# Mutate() error is caused when trying to subtract values from 2 different columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, reshape

I have the code below in which I basically subtract the values on column `qty` based on if they have the same value in column `activity` and with the logic `in-out` from the `in_out` column. The result will be saved in the `qty_scrap` column.

The result dataframe will then have 4 columns. The activity `column` with the unique name of the `activity`, the `in` column with the `in` value of the `qty`, the `out` column with the `out` value of the `qty` and the qty_scrap column with their difference.

but I get:

```
error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `qty_scrap = `in` - out`.
Caused by error in `` `in` - out ``:
p<-structure(list(case_id = c(3396922, 3396922, 3396922, 3396922, 
                              3396922, 3396922, 3396922, 3396922, 3397364, 3397364, 3397364, 
                              3397364, 3397364, 3397364, 3397364, 3397364, 3397364, 3397364, 
                              3397364, 3397364), action = c("3396922-RAAMELK", "3396922-RAAMELK", 
                                                            "3396922-Separering", "3396922-Separering", "3396922-P11-R", 
                                                            "3396922-P11-R", "3396922-T51-R", "3396922-T51-R", "3397364-RAAMELK", 
                                                            "3397364-RAAMELK", "3397364-Separering", "3397364-Separering", 
                                                            "3397364-P10-R", "3397364-P10-R", "3397364-T42-R", "3397364-T42-R", 
                                                            "3397364-T61-R", "3397364-T61-R", "3397364-T41-R", "3397364-T41-R"
                              ), resource = c("RAAMELK", "RAAMELK", "Separering", "Separering", 
                                              "P11-R", "P11-R", "T51-R", "T51-R", "RAAMELK", "RAAMELK", "Separering", 
                                              "Separering", "P10-R", "P10-R", "T42-R", "T42-R", "T61-R", "T61-R", 
                                              "T41-R", "T41-R"), lifecycle = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 
                                                                               2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6), registration_type = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                              2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                              2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("start", "complete"), class = "factor"), 
                  timestamp = structure(c(1667266620, 1667269440, 1667266620, 
                                          1667269500, 1667266620, 1667269500, 1667291460, 1667304000, 
                                          1667523600, 1667531220, 1667531220, 1667531220, 1667523600, 
                                          1667531220, 1667548320, 1667556720, 1667528880, 1667535420, 
                                          1667624400, 1667635860), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                  activity = c("RAAMELK", "RAAMELK", "Separering", "Separering", 
                               "Sweetmilk Pasteurizer 8332", "Sweetmilk Pasteurizer 8332", 
                               "9005 - T51 kartong 70x70", "9005 - T51 kartong 70x70", "RAAMELK", 
                               "RAAMELK", "Separering", "Separering", "Sweetmilk Pasteurizer 8331", 
                               "Sweetmilk Pasteurizer 8331", "9004 - T42 kartong 70x70", 
                               "9004 - T42 kartong 70x70", "9006 - T61 BIB", "9006 - T61 BIB", 
                               "9004 - T41 kartong 70x70", "9004 - T41 kartong 70x70"), 
                  activity_description = c("Forbrukt r\xe5melk", "Forbrukt r\xe5melk", 
                                           "Utbytte r\xe5fl\xf8te", "Utbytte r\xe5fl\xf8te", "Pasteurisert melk til tank", 
                                           "Pasteurisert melk til tank", "Produsert melk", "Produsert melk", 
                                           "Forbrukt r\xe5melk", "Forbrukt r\xe5melk", "Utbytte r\xe5fl\xf8te", 
                                           "Utbytte r\xe5fl\xf8te", "Pasteurisert melk til tank", "Pasteurisert melk til tank", 
                                           "Produsert melk", "Produsert melk", "Produsert melk", "Produsert melk", 
                                           "Produsert melk", "Produsert melk"), ...9 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                         NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                         NA, NA), product = c("K101149", "K101149", "K101149", "K101149", 
                                                                                                              "K101149", "K101149", "K101149", "K101149", "K101152", "K101152", 
                                                                                                              "K101152", "K101152", "K101152", "K101152", "K101152", "K101152", 
                                                                                                              "K101152", "K101152", "K101152", "K101152"), product_type_text = c("200100 - Milk", 
                                                                                                                                                                                 "200100 - Milk", "200100 - Milk", "200100 - Milk", "200100 - Milk", 
                                                                                                                                                                                 "200100 - Milk", "200100 - Milk", "200100 - Milk", "200100 - Milk", 
                                                                                                                                                                                 "200100 - Milk", "200100 - Milk", "200100 - Milk", "200100 - Milk", 
                                                                                                                                                                                 "200100 - Milk", "200100 - Milk", "200100 - Milk", "200100 - Milk", 
                                                                                                                                                                                 "200100 - Milk", "200100 - Milk", "200100 - Milk"), qty = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             19976.92, 19976.92, 2386, 17590.92, 17481, 17480, 17694, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             NA, 31, 31, 9, 31, 31, 6, 6, 3, 3, 28, 28), in_out = c("in", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "out", "in", "out", "in", "out", "in", "out", "in", "out", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "in", "out", "in", "out", "in", "out", "in", "out", "in", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "out"), qty_scrap = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 109.92, NA, -214, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -270.64, NA, 524, NA, 260, NA, NA), `FP ordre` = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3513481, 3513481, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 NA, 3395035, 3395035, 4531159, 4531159, 4385337, 4385337), 
                  Artikkeltype = c("SF", "SF", "SF", "SF", "SF", "SF", "FP", 
                                   "FP", "SF", "SF", "SF", "SF", "SF", "SF", "FP", "FP", "FP", 
                                   "FP", "FP", "FP"), .order = 1:20), row.names = c(NA, -20L
                                   ), class = c("eventlog", "log", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                   ), case_id = "case_id", activity_id = "activity", activity_instance_id = "action", lifecycle_id = "registration_type", resource_id = "resource", timestamp = "timestamp")

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
vol<-p[,c("activity","qty","in_out","qty_scrap")]
    vol<-as.data.frame(vol)
    
    
    
    vol[is.na(vol)] <- 0
    vol<-vol %>% 
      pivot_wider(id_cols = "activity", names_from = "in_out", values_from = "qty") %>% 
      mutate(qty_scrap = `in`-out)
```

Comment: Don‘t put the column name 'in' in quotation marks. Just type in-out.

Comment: it does not work again

Comment: The problem is not in the subtraction, but in `pivot_wider`. Your `id_cols` variable is not unique, so you get "list-cols" (you should get a warning about that). Can you post the "vol" dataframe you obtain after pivoting and before you tray to add the new column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are duplicates before reshaping into wide format, you may want to add `case_id`.

```
vol <- p[c('case_id', "activity","qty","in_out","qty_scrap")] |> as.data.frame()
```

Then try `reshape`.

```
reshape(vol, idvar=c('case_id','activity'), timevar='in_out', direction='wide') |>
  transform(qty_scrap=qty.in - qty.out)
#    case_id                   activity   qty.in qty_scrap.in  qty.out qty_scrap.out qty_scrap
# 1  3396922                    RAAMELK     0.00            0 19976.92          0.00 -19976.92
# 3  3396922                 Separering 19976.92            0  2386.00          0.00  17590.92
# 5  3396922 Sweetmilk Pasteurizer 8332 17590.92            0 17481.00        109.92    109.92
# 7  3396922   9005 - T51 kartong 70x70 17480.00            0 17694.00       -214.00   -214.00
# 9  3397364                    RAAMELK     0.00            0    31.00          0.00    -31.00
# 11 3397364                 Separering    31.00            0     9.00          0.00     22.00
# 13 3397364 Sweetmilk Pasteurizer 8331    31.00            0    31.00       -270.64      0.00
# 15 3397364   9004 - T42 kartong 70x70     6.00            0     6.00        524.00      0.00
# 17 3397364             9006 - T61 BIB     3.00            0     3.00        260.00      0.00
# 19 3397364   9004 - T41 kartong 70x70    28.00            0    28.00          0.00      0.00
```

Instead of `transform` you can still use `dplyr::mutate`.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, your `pivot_wider` call is generating list columns. The reason why `mutate` is throwing an error is that you cannot subtract list columns from each other. You can get round this by `unnest`ing the list columns before the `mutate` step:

```r
vol %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = "activity", names_from = "in_out", values_from = "qty",
              values_fn = list) %>%
  unnest(cols = c("in", "out")) %>%
  mutate(qty_scrap = `in` - out)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>    activity                     `in`    out qty_scrap
#>    <chr>                       <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1 RAAMELK                        0  19977.   -19977.
#>  2 RAAMELK                        0     31       -31 
#>  3 Separering                 19977.  2386     17591.
#>  4 Separering                    31      9        22 
#>  5 Sweetmilk Pasteurizer 8332 17591. 17481       110.
#>  6 9005 - T51 kartong 70x70   17480  17694      -214 
#>  7 Sweetmilk Pasteurizer 8331    31     31         0 
#>  8 9004 - T42 kartong 70x70       6      6         0 
#>  9 9006 - T61 BIB                 3      3         0 
#> 10 9004 - T41 kartong 70x70      28     28         0
```